# The meaning of 'earrings that announced their names thrice over'

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I heard the fear in the first music I ever knew, the music that pumped
>   from boom boxes full of grand boast and bluster. The boys who stood
>   out on Garrison and Liberty up on Park Heights loved this music
>   because it told them, against all evidence and odds, that they were
>   masters of their own lives, their own streets, and their own bodies. I
>   saw it in the girls, in their loud laughter, in their gilded bamboo
>   earrings **that announced their names thrice over**.

-*Between the World and Me* by Ta-Nehisi Coates

How the earrings can announce someone's name? Is there such an expression?

Comment: [Google search on `bamboo earrings with your name`](https://www.google.com/search?q=bamboo+earrings+with+your+name).

Comment: @TRomano... Seriously? Never seen one before!  Thank you.

Comment: @TRomano - I wonder why thrice over, then. After all, most earrings are worn in pairs.

Comment: @J.R.  thrice over- maybe used in a hyperbolic sense?

Comment: **Thrice** is odd in the context of ears, true.  Presumably the name is being "shouted" by these very big earrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this book (*Between the World and Me*) it means exactly what it says: the earrings bear the wearer's name three times (or "thrice").

Comment: Right. So their names were inscribed in the earrings.